# tomcat giving classnotfoundexception on com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport when it is present in WEB-INF/lib

Tags: tomcat, struts2

I am trying to deploy a directory in tomcat which contains following struts2 related jars in its **WEB-INF/lib** folder :-

```
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
freemarker-2.3.19.jar
javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
xwork-core-2.3.8.jar
commons-lang3-3.1.jar
ognl-3.0.6.jar
struts2-core-2.3.8.jar  // and some jars containing business-logic
```

However, on deploying this directory in tomcat, it throws **ClassNotFoundException** in following manner :-

```
Dec 27, 2013 4:42:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.listener.StrutsListener
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionSupport
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:788)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:447)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    ...and 26 more

    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 42 more
```

which is really weird because **"xwork-core-2.3.8.jar"**, in WEB-INF/lib folder, contains the same class which has reported missing by tomcat, i.e., com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport. What's even more weird is that I tried to deploy the same directory on another computer and it worked perfectly. I have no idea what went wrong here. I would appreciate help in sorting this out.

Here's the **web.xml** that I wrote:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>KrozonaService</display-name>
  <filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <filter-class>
          org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
      </filter-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>actionPackages</param-name>
         <param-value>com.krozona.databaseaccess.gatewayService</param-value>
      </init-param>
      </filter>
         <filter-mapping>
           <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
           </filter-mapping>
      <listener>
          <listener-class>
              org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.listener.StrutsListener
           </listener-class>
      </listener>
      <welcome-file-list>
          <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And here'the **struts.xml** :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd" >
<struts>
  <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
  <package name="Krozona" namespace="/" extends="struts-default" >

      <action name="GetTags" 
           class="com.krozona.databaseaccess.gatewayService.GetTagsAction" 
           method="execute">
           <result name="success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
      </action>
  </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: please show your web.xml

Comment: Added web.xml and struts.xml

Comment: Provides  your tomcat server already xwork-code jar with different version. Could be a version conflict.

Comment: At least you can work on another comp, check tomcat lib folder if it contains a library xwork-core-x.x.x.jar.

Comment: Yeah, putting the jar in TOMCAT/lib folder solves it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's weird, but, putting the same jar in **TOMCAT/lib** instead of **webapp/WEB-INF/lib** solves the problem. No idea why, but it works.